# copying file from pc to windows phone

Tags: c#, wifi, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows application for transferring files 
from PC to Windows Phone over Wi-Fi.

If Windows Phone is connected to a PC via Wi-Fi, can I get the Windows Phone IP address so that I can use the Copy function to copy the file from the PC to the device using its IP address?

If there is any other way than this except USB then please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You will need a desktop client for that too.